# php-fpm config - include more tahn on globbed path

Tags: php

I know the php-fpm.conf "include-..." directive can have a globbed value like

```
include=/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf
```

But how can I also have an other globbed path that should be included like "/chroots/www_*/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf"

Is the "include=..." directive a comma separated value? Like:

```
include=/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf,/chroots/www_*/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf
```

or colon separated? Like"

```
include=/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf:/chroots/www_*/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf
```

Or is is it possible to use more that one globbed path at all?

thanks, Alex.